# Google Sheets -Publish to web - Webpage Security Flaw

Tags: google-sheets, publish

I have a neat feedback system created via google sheets where each employee in the company is rated and their ratings are shared via individual emails at the end of each month.

To avert this time-consuming struggle, I figured I could use the 'Publish to the web' feature. I created a separate tab for each employee and will update the same tab with each month's ratings. I will publish each tab to the web so that the separate GID's are created.

What I know for a fact is that each separate URL will now show the respective employee's ratings. However, with a bit of tinkering, I found the major flaw. The main URL is common to all the sheets and the GID determines the tab that needs to be displayed on the published web page.

BUT

There is a tail part of this URL where `single=true`. If this is modified to `single=false` all hell breaks loose. Anyone will be able to view all the tabs in this instance. Below is the URL:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQV3oDUBNDqkjyAlA3iG3SzaYkWXMBcrAZLJia8iG0cLB4s_wGpRHbl4UAeXose0kljLMepk1FP_vf1/pubhtml?gid=667555873&single=true

(note the `single=true` at the end)

This is a very big problem as I cannot have any employee figuring out this supremely easy trick and then be able to view EVERYBODY's ratings - that would be a major issue.

Is there any solution to this? How come Google hasn't addressed this? If I really wanted to publish the whole sheet/report, I would do that from the Google sheets settings. Certainly, a minor URL change should not affect the display settings, right?

[image: Screenshot of single=true]

[image: Screenshot of single=false]

Answer (score 0):

Would a link shortener help? It depends if the shortened link would replace the original or simply redirect to the original page.